# Keeping track of all values created by a sequence for multiple inserts

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sequence, dblink

In PL SQL, I'm writing a stored procedure that uses a DB link:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Order_Migration(us_id IN NUMBER, date_id in DATE) 
as 
begin
  INSERT INTO ORDERS(order_id, company_id)
  SELECT ORDER_ID_SEQ.nextval, COMPANY_ID 
  FROM ORDERS@SOURCE
  WHERE USER_ID = us_id  AND DUE_DATE = date_ID;   
end;
```

It takes all orders done on a certain day, by a certain user and inserts them in the new database. It calls a sequence to makes sure there are no repeat PKs on the orders, and it works well.

However, I want the same procedure to do a second INSERT into another table that has order_id as a foreign key. So I need to add all the order_id's just created, and the data from SOURCE that matches:

```
INSERT INTO  ORDER_COMPLETION(order_id, completion_dt)
SELECT ????, completion_dt                    
FROM ORDER_COMPLETION@SOURCE
```

How can I keep track of which order_id that was just created matches up to the one whose data I need to pull from the source database?

I looked into making a temporary table, but you can't create those in a procedure.

Other info: I'll be calling this procedure from a C# app I'm writing

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure that I follow the question.  If there is an `ORDERS` table and an `ORDER_COMPLETION` table in the remote database, wouldn't there be some key on the source system that related those two tables?  If that key is the `ORDER_ID`, why would you want to re-assign that key in your procedure?  Wouldn't you want to maintain the `ORDER_ID` from the source system?

If you do want to re-assign the `ORDER_ID` locally, I would tend to think that you'd want to do something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE order_migration( p_user_id IN orders.user_id%type,
                                             p_due_date IN orders.due_date%type )
AS
  TYPE order_rec IS RECORD( new_order_id  NUMBER,
                            old_order_id  NUMBER,
                            company_id    NUMBER,
                            completion_dt DATE );
  TYPE order_arr IS TABLE OF order_rec;
  l_orders order_arr;
BEGIN
  SELECT order_id_seq.nextval,
         o.order_id,
         o.company_id,
         oc.completion_dt
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_orders
    FROM orders@source o,
         order_completion@source oc
   WHERE o.order_id = oc.order_id
     AND o.user_id  = p_user_id
     AND o.due_date = p_due_date;

  FORALL i IN l_orders.FIRST .. l_orders.LAST
    INSERT INTO orders( order_id, company_id )
      VALUES( l_orders(i).new_order_id, l_orders(i).company_id );

  FORALL i IN l_orders.FIRST .. l_orders.LAST
    INSERT INTO order_completion( order_id, completion_dt )
      VALUES( l_orders(i).new_order_id, l_orders(i).completion_dt );
END;
```

You could also do a single `FOR` loop with two `INSERT` statements rather than two `FORALL` loops.  And if you're pulling a lot of data each time, you probably want to pull the data in chunks from the remote system by adding a loop and a `LIMIT` to the `BULK COLLECT`

Comment: Thanks for the help. The key that relates is order_id. And because it is the PK of ORDERS, there is a trigger that doesn't allow inserts of repeat values. Both the DBs are used frequently, so this is highly likely. I'm looking into using this info here.

Comment: @null - I'm still not sure I follow.  Do you really have a hand-coded trigger trying to enforce a primary key rather than declaring the column as a primary key and letting Oracle enforce it with an index?  Is `ORDER_ID` the primary key of the `ORDERS` table both locally and on the remote machine?  Is your goal that a particular `ORDER_ID` can exist on both the local database and on the remote database and reference completely different orders?  That seems likely to cause a great deal of confusion over time.

Comment: I did make a mistake in saying there was a trigger. I wrote trigger while thinking of the index. And that issue will happen, but it actually shouldn't cause too much of an issue for us.

Comment: @null - Is "that issue" the issue of the `ORDER_ID` referring to different orders in the local and remote database?  If you used the `ORDER_ID` from the remote system rather than reassigning it, it wouldn't happen at all.  That still seems like the more sensible approach.

Comment: Unfortunately it's part of the specifications. I'm an intern and need to do what my supervisor says. However when I began to work on this, I got an error, that `FORALL` can not be used on a remote system, even though I'm looping through my equivalent of `l_orders`. Any ideas?

Comment: @null - Can you post the code you're using and the exact Oracle error message (including the ORA-xxxxx code)?

Comment: @JustinCave let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2420/discussion-between-null-and-justin-cave)

Answer (score 1):

There must be some link between the rows in ORDERS@SOURCE and ORDERS, and between ORDERS@SOURCE and ORDER_COMPLETION@SOURCE, so can you not use a join?

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO  ORDER_COMPLETION(order_id, completion_dt)
SELECT o.order_id, ocs.completion_dt                    
FROM ORDER_COMPLETION@SOURCE ocs
JOIN ORDERS o ON o.xxx = ocs.xxx
```